# Lock/edit Word / RTF documents generated by FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am generating forms for users to fill. I am using FastReport to generate RTF files.

Is there any way to restrict user changes in the RTF file to specific areas ?
I can do that in Word, but if it can be done in fastReport as it generates the files all the better.

### UPDATE:

I want to know if it can be automatically done with fastreport as it generates the RTF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. Since the RTF file basically just hold rich text formatting only. My suggestion is do further processing with RTF data and convert it into Word format (or PDF maybe).

Answer (score 0):

There is no normal way to restrict users from modifying a RTF (text file with special characters in it) when you use normal editors.

You have to write your own RTF editor and specify which areas may or maynot be edited.

By the way this question has nothing to do with Delphi and FastReport... Try to find a better place for this question.